# "must subset elements with a valid subscript vector. x subscript must be a simple vector, not a matrix." in rpart

Tags: r, rpart

I am attempting to run recursive partitioning on a large dataset but continue encountering an error that I cannot solve. Code below:

```
library(rpart)
library(haven)
library(tidyverse)

my.data <- read_sav("my.data.sav")

goal_binary_notxhx <- rpart(binary_change_6mo ~ fm9008a + fm9009a + fm9010a + fm9011a + fm9012a 
                            + fm9013a + fm9014a + fm9015a + fm9016a + fm9017a + fm9018a, 
                            data = my.data, method = 'anova', 
                            control = (xval = 10))
```

Data using dput:

```
structure(list(fm9008a = structure(c(90, 89, 79, 90, 90, 77), label = "Living in House", format.spss = "F4.2", display_width = 9L), 
fm9009a = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14), label = "Living Rent Free", format.spss = "F4.2", display_width = 9L), 
fm9010a = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Living in Halfway House", format.spss = "F4.2", display_width = 9L), 
fm9011a = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Living Homeless", format.spss = "F4.2", display_width = 9L), 
fm9012a = structure(c(2, 1, 3, 0, 2, 0), label = "Living Under Medical Care", format.spss = "F4.2", display_width = 9L), 
fm9013a = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Alcohol Sessions", format.spss = "F4.2", display_width = 9L), 
fm9014a = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Drug Sessions", format.spss = "F4.2", display_width = 9L), 
fm9015a = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Emotional Sessions", format.spss = "F4.2", display_width = 9L), 
fm9016a = structure(c(0, 3, 6, 0, 1, 0), label = "12-Step Sessions", format.spss = "F4.2", display_width = 9L), 
fm9017a = structure(c(63, 58, 4, 73, 63, 63), label = "Work Days", format.spss = "F4.2", display_width = 9L), 
fm9018a = structure(c(0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "School Days", format.spss = "F4.2", display_width = 9L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
binary_change_6mo = structure(c(1, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA), label = "Binary goal change from 0 to 6mo", format.spss = "F8.2", labels = c(`no change` = 0, 
change = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
))
```

My error message is as follows:

```
Error: Must subset elements with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript must be a simple vector, not a matrix.
```

I have tried changing the imported data into a data frame but get the same error and am not sure how to proceed.

```
df.my.data <- as.data.frame(my.data)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: Please let me know if my edits to the original question suffice. Thanks!

Comment: To attempt to replicate this, someone would need `binary_change_6mo`, in addition to data above. And welcome to SOF. To simplify, I guess I'd just import rpart, though I guess the `.sav` requires haven or tidyverse. try `debugonce` on rpart and step thru to where it errors while you `ls` your objects along the way so see if they are the desired vector for indexing/subscripting.

Comment: Thanks, @Chris. I added data for `binary_change_6mo`. I tried using `debugonce` with limited success (pretty new to R as well as SOF). I did try changing outcome variable and the model would run which makes me think the issue is with the `binary_change_6mo`. However, the model ran before so I am confused about what might have changed.